# copying many files from sharepoint to other using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I m trying to copy documents from list in one sharepoint to another :

this is my code :

```
*************************************************
$source= "\\...\s1"
$destination = "\\..\s2"

foreach ($result in $result )

{ copy-item -path $source -dest $destination}
*************************************************
```

`-$result` is the list of all documents that I got using web-services, it s type is system.array

`-$source` and `$destination` are UNC that refers to URL of the two sharepoint

the error is

> " can not find the path \...\s1system.xml.Xml.XmlElement"

PS: I m not using server machine,it s just a client

Here is my code

```
*****************************************************




{

  param (

    [String]$Value,
    [String]$Field,
    [String]$RowLimit = "0",
    [String]$Operator = "Contains",
    [String]$WebURL = "https://.................../wer",
    [String]$ListName = "Main documents",
    [String]$ViewName,
    [Switch]$Recurse
)
$ScriptDirectory = split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$dllPath = "P:\SamlCookieAuth.dll" -f $ScriptDirectory
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllPath)

$queryOptionsValue = ''
if ($Recurse)
{
    $queryOptionsValue = '<ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>'
}

$WSUri = $WebURL + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl"
$listsWebServiceReference = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WSUri -UseDefaultCredential
$listsWebServiceReference.Url = $webURL + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"

[System.Uri]$CookieUri = $WebURL
$listsWebServiceReference.CookieContainer = [ST.SamlCookieAuth.SamlCookieManager]::GetAuthenticatedCookiesContainer($CookieUri.AbsoluteUri, 0, 0)

[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xmlDoc = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
[System.Xml.XmlElement]$queryOptions =$xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions")
$queryOptions.InnerXml = $queryOptionsValue

if ($PSBoundParameters.Keys.Contains("Value"))
{
    [System.Xml.XmlElement]$query = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query")
    $queryValue = "<Where><$Operator><FieldRef Name='$Field'/><Value Type='Text'>$Value</Value></$Operator></Where>"
    $query.InnerXml = $queryValue
    $result=$listsWebServiceReference.GetListItems($listName, $viewName, $query, $null, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, $null).data.row
}
else
{
    $result=$listsWebServiceReference.GetListItems($listName, $viewName, $null, $null, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, $null).data.row
}




 $destDirectory = "\\.............\TER\Main Documents"

foreach ($resul in $result)

 {Copy-Item -path $resul -destination $destDirectory } 

}
```

Comment: `foreach ($result in $result)` looks suspicious to me. I'd try `foreach ($doc in $result)`. Also you should inspect what's in this array - it could be that you'll have to access a property to pass to `copy-item` instead of the complete object.

Comment: it's a listeName that i get using the command new-webserviceproxy.It contains properties like : ows_linkFileName , ows_modified.....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem that you are having is the result of a conversion issue. You are trying to write content from one SP to another as a document, however, you cannot do so with an XmlElement.

Suggest checking out this post: 
[Converting system.xml.xmlelement to system.xml.xmldocument with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138664/converting-system-xml-xmlelement-to-system-xml-xmldocument-with-powershell)

It would be helpful to see the content of "-$result is the list of all documents that I got using web-services, it s type is system.array".

Also, for readability, I would suggest differentiating between `$result` and `$result` as follows:

```
foreach($document in $documentList){}
```

-or- (at minimum)

```
foreach($result in $results){}
```

Comment: Can you see may Code please?